# LPc11u68 Recognized as an USB mass storage device even when programmed in HID class

Tags: usb-device, lpc, nxp, hid, cortex-m0

When I connected a newbie LPC11u68 to USB port,it recognized in windows as an USB mass storage device.When I  programmed LPCOPEN HID example by Flash magic to it,after resetting the board,my PC can't recognized it.Only when I pulled down PIO0_1(ISP selection pin)it still recognized as a Mass storage device.???
[LPC11u68's Datasheet.](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC11U6X.pdf)
I'm using a simple header board with USB port(As i said PC successfully recognized 11u68 as mass storage devices ,then I think there are no hardware fault). Also I'm using LPCXPRESSO IDE v8.0.0,I tried all of the USBD examples in the LPCXPRESSO boards LPCOPEN examples, and they programmed successfully to the chip,also I config a LED to blink. In all of them LED blinked which means MCU is running , but when I connect board to the USB port of my PC,I cant see it in the USB or HID section of my PC's device manager. I don't checked SWD, is LPC11u68 support it? WBR.
**EDIT**:know when I compiled LPC11u68 lpcopen HID examples for the manley 11u68 board ,devices appear in the devices manager but after a second it disappear while I don't disconnect it.
[image: like this picture]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is clear if you read it a once completely ! Why LPC11u68 recognized as mass storage when I programmed it in HID class(why does not  recognized as a HID device)?

Comment: It's still in bootloader mode. If you link the datasheet here someone might point you at the section telling you how to get it out of bootloader and into run mode. Complete circuit diagram would also be useful (is it e.g. stuck in reset)?

Comment: I'm using  a simple header board with USB port(As i said PC successfully recognized 11u68 as mass storage devices ,then I think there are no hardware fault).
Also I'm using LPCXPRESSO IDE v8.0.0,I tried all of the USBD examples in the LPCXPRESSO boards LPCOPEN examples, and they programmed successfully to the chip,also I config a LED to blink.
In all of them LED blinked which means MCU is running , but when I connect board to the USB port of my PC,I cant see it in the USB or HID section of my PC's device manager.
I don't checked SWD, is LPC11u68 support it?
WBR.

Answer (score 1):

With adding a 10uf tantal cap to the power line it is working fine know.
thank you every one.